# TPS3619-33 (Backup-Battery Supervisor) overdrawing current at the VBAT path after a few runs

Tags: troubleshooting, supervisor

I've been having a few problems in integrating the TPS3619-33 (Backup-Battery Supervisor) into a product that I've been working on for quite a while. After installing a new TPS3619 into the board after a few hook-ups at the VBAT input with a variable bench linear power supply the IC starts to over draw current, bearing in mind that if the current was not limited by the power supply the IC would definitely burnout (right now limited to 10mA and unfortunately it is maxed out) and I've disconnected the load and it is clear now the TPS3619 is the one drawing the current. At this state the IC can still switch between Vbat and VDD automatically, but it is clear that it is not advised to continue using the IC in this state and a replacement is required, but I would really appreciate if someone would advise what would cause this behavior.

VBAT: 3.0-3.6V

VDD: 3.2-3.3V

[image]

What I have in mind of possible suspects,

1. ESD, maybe VBAT needs an ESD diode?
2. PFO is directly connected to the MCU GPIO (0 - 3.3V), I'm not sure maybe some condition that may fry the IC?
3. The bench power supply connectors arcing or overshooting maybe during power on/off at the VBAT input? (Siglent SPD3303X-E ).

I would really appreciate if someone would share their experience and/or thoughts on this subject.

Comment: I would love to know if you found an answer I am working on similar project

Comment: sorry for the late reply, turns out that the VBAT - VOUT rail is rated maximum 10mA , my load would spike around 100mA few seconds before plunging down to 1mA, turns out the IC could not handle that and it would  slowly deteriorate ( resistances between Vout and gnd , Vbat and gnd and VDD and gnd would get lower and lower until they short ) .